# Class per command or not - best practices

Tags: c#, .net, cqrs

Let's say that I have two commands `CreateCarCommand` and `UpdateCarCommand` and they obviously share some properties.

What is the best practice, should I create separate classes per command like

```
public class CreateCarCommand { ... } 
public class UpdateCarCommand { ... }
```

or should `UpdateCarCommand` inherit from `CreateCarCommand`

```
public class CreateCarCommand { ... } 
public class UpdateCarCommand : CarCommand { ... }
```

Comment: These look like CRUD commands, with `Car` just a payload. A base command would be useful but probably *not* car-related

Answer (score 3):

I would have **two separate** command classes - and if you have a lot of common properties, use a `CarCommandBase` base class and make `CreateCarCommand` and `UpdateCarCommand` inherit from that base class:

```
public class CarCommandBase
{
    // define common properties and possibly methods here
}

public class CreateCarCommand : CarCommandBase
{   
    // custom code
} 

public class UpdateCarCommand : CarCommandBase
{   
    // custom code
}
```

Comment: Definitely separate. And even that would start a discussion on inheritance vs composition vs ..... Is `Car` the common property here? Or are these `CRUD` commands with `Car` as the payload?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with you. For `CRUD` operations its not necessary.